# JavaScript regexp with '/' within the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a node application that works with mongodb (native driver). I have  docs with a field "parent" for example, `"parent":"root/test/dir/"`. This is how I try to find all the docs that the "parent" field contains for example "root/test". `db.collection.find({"parent": new Regexp("root/test")})` it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `"root\/test"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Blobonat points out, you can use the back slash character to over-ride the special meaning of the following character in a regular expression.

`new Regexp("root\/test")`

The MDN is a good resource for this:

> A backslash that precedes a special character indicates that the next character is not special and should be interpreted literally.

Likewise the inverse holds true.

> A backslash that precedes a non-special character indicates that the next character is special and is not to be interpreted literally.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

There is also a great set of example [here from a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) for working with URLs and RegExp

Comment: For extra fun strings like `this\that` become `this\\that` because you have to backslash the backslash, which leads to some hard to real regex expressions like `\\/([^;]+);version=`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with mongodb driver. The remove function didn't work for me. What did work is the `deleteMany`. My regexp was fine, I loged it out and as the answers above sad it was `/\root/\test'`. `new Regexp` works great.